# @DataMongoTest fails because of UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-test, spring-mongo

I'd like to test my repository method. However when I run my test, it fails because of `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. It for some reason tries to create `AuthorizationServerConfig` (or other bean if I remove @Configuration annotation from this one). It fails cause deeper in dependencies chain it requires RabbitMQ connection pool, that I prefer to not provide in repository test.

The question is why Spring tries to create all those beans not linked to repository logic?

I attempted to exclude all those beans with `@DataMongoTest(exludeFilters: ...)` and `@DataMongoTest(exludeAutoConfiguration: ...)` but it had no effect.

The only thing that helped was to add @Profile("!test") to all beans (all! controllers, services, components) in an application, but it smells like a very ugly solution.

Repository class is very simple:

```java
    @Repository
    public interface ParticipantRepository extends MongoRepository<Participant, String> {
        List<Participant> findAllByLoggedInTrueAndAccessTokenExpirationAfter(Date expirationAfter);
    }
```

My test class:

```java
    @DataMongoTest()
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class ParticipantRepositoryTest {

        @Autowired
        private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
        @Autowired
        private ParticipantRepository repository;

        private List<Participant> participants;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            participants = createParticipants();
            repository.saveAll(participants);
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            repository.deleteAll();
        }

        @Test
        public void findAllByLoggedInTrueAndExpirationAfter_shouldNotReturnLoggedOutParticipants() {
            List<Participant> result = repository.findAllByLoggedInTrueAndAccessTokenExpirationAfter(new Date());

            getLoggedOutParticipants().forEach(participant -> assertThat(participant, not(isIn(result))));
        }
    ...
    }
```